# Small projector for watching movies/playing game

Tags: projector

I'm currently relocating once every one or two months and as I have not much luggage space on my <s>car</s> motorbike, I can't move around my PC and my 26 inches screen and I'm stuck with just my laptop.

So, I'm thinking to buy a cheap mini projector to plug into the laptop to watch movies and play games and need some advice, as it's a field I've never looked into.

What I'd need:

- Decent screen size, maybe at least a 42 inches?
- Decent resolution, no needs for FullHD but at least something more than a 1366×768
- HDMI input
- Small. Even better, lightweight.
- Silent
- I have no idea of prices, but if possible...no more than 100 euro?
- decent quality, I need text to be readable

Nothing else, and I mean it literally: I'm ok in trading everything else for the above features. I'll be using it only at night so (reasonably) low lumens is ok, I don't need usb ports, no wifi, nothing nothing nothing.

Comment: broad request is broad.  And while having a lot of requested variables, is not very specific in terms of definition of said variables.

Answer (score 1):

This one is under budget, and meets all of your other criteria. Seems like a solid little piece of hardware, I might pick one up...

It sounds like your travelling alot. I would consider getting a small bit of [projector cloth](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007KA07YM) and 4 push pins. I doubt hotel staff would see the pin holes, and it would make your experience with any projector better. You can cut the cloth down to the size you'd prefer, or just let the remainder hang loose. When your done, it should fold up nicely and go back into your bag.

[Crenova Mini Projector](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FJFTNB2)

Comment: You know, I think OP has fallen off the planet.  Yet this still gets moved to the front page by the Community-bot

Comment: @NZKshatriya That seems to be a slight issue with the Community-Bot... Bumping questions to the top that are very unlikely to be accepted because the OP has not been seen in ages (when you check their profile).